# How to use XTS period.apply() using TTR indicator functions?

Tags: r, xts, quantitative-finance

I can't seem to use TTR indicator functions direclty with period.apply() from XTS. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
> require(TTR)
> require(quantmod)
> require(xts)
> data(sample_matrix)

> period.apply(sample_matrix, endpoints(sample_matrix,"weeks"), RSI)

Error in EMA(c(NA, 0.190714286249097, 0.190459011271606, 0, 0, 0, NA,  : 
  Invalid 'n'
```

I also tried to `as.xts(sample_matrix)` first but it doesn't help.

Comment: The error in your example is because of `RSI`'s default `n=10` and there are no weeks with 10 days.  You're also sending an OHLC object to RSI, which expects a univariate object.  Even if you fix those issues, `?period.apply` says it applies a function to non-overlapping intervals along a vector and returns a vector the length of INDEX-1; you're trying to return a vector the same length as `sample_matrix`.  Rather than just posting code that doesn't work, it would be helpful if you told us what you're tying to accomplish.

Comment: @joshu-ulrich Thanks for pointing out my errors. I'm trying to make use of [code]endpoints(sample_matrix, 'weeks', k = 2)[/code] in period.apply so that I can get RSI values on a 2-week period series. The to.period() methods don't support non-unity periods (e.g. 2, 3 weeks rather than 1) so I thought this might do.

Comment: Paul, `to.period` most certainly support non-unity periods.  That's what the `k` argument is for (e.g. `to.period(sample_matrix, "weeks", 2)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to your question, I think you want something like this:

```
> RSI(Cl(to.period(sample_matrix, "weeks", 2)),4)
               [,1]
2007-01-07       NA
2007-01-21       NA
2007-02-04       NA
2007-02-18       NA
2007-03-04 58.42659
2007-03-18 40.25955
2007-04-01 27.12793
2007-04-15 50.26745
2007-04-29 38.97652
2007-05-13 22.03943
2007-05-27 28.75952
2007-06-10 22.21261
2007-06-24 21.58207
2007-06-30 41.69338
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I can't believe I missed that 'k' option in to.period()!